# Mongoose check if user owns document before updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to check if a **user** owns a document before updating it *or* deleting it, and would like to keep this as DRY as possible. Ideally, I would **not** have to make **two** calls to the database where I would first `findById().then(doc => {check if user owns document and then -> doc.findByIdAndUpdate() })` but rather keep this as one call to the DB.

I am constantly having to execute this check on *express routes* and have thought about implementing this layer of logic on the mongoose `.pre('update')` middleware. but am unaware how to pass the incoming **userid** from the **req object** to my middleware validation function?

Are there any better layers to implement this checking functionality? or am I going to have to make the two requests to the database every time I want to check if a user owns a document and write this out in every express route?

My current implementation is:

```
const addDocToDoc = (req, res, next) => {
    let doc1id = req.params.id;
    let doc2id  = req.params.doc2id;
    Doc1.findById(doc1id)
        .then(doc1 => {
            if(userCanAlter(doc1, req.user, res)) {
                doc1.doc2s.push(doc2id)
                return doc1.save().then(updatedDoc1 => res.send(updatedDoc1))
            }
        }).catch(next)
}
```

Where `userCanAlter()` looks like this:

```
function userCanAlter(instance, user, res) {
        if (!instance) { res.status(404).send("Document does not exist."); return false}
        if (instance.user != user) { res.status(401).send("User unauthorized"); return false}
        else return true;
    }
```

Obviously, this is a very simple update but the more complex updates would require more configuration before saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current implementation in question found to be the best & DRY’est implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your user in **find** query and use **findOne()**, Something like:

```
const addDocToDoc = (req, res, next) => {
    const {
        user = ''
    } = req;
    const {
        id = '', doc2id = ''
    } = req.params;
    Doc1.findOne({
            _id: id,
            user
        })
        .then(doc => {
            if (!doc) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: 'User Not Found!!'
                });
            }
            doc.doc2s.push(doc2id);
            doc.save()
                .then(updatedDoc1 => res.status(200).json(updatedDoc1))
                .catch(err => res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error While Updating!!',
                    error: err
                }));
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error While Fetching!!',
            error: err
        }));
}
```

Also I'd suggest if you work a bit on naming things, as this may mess up things a few times.

In case if you wanna throw specific error for unauthorized user, you can stick to your way of implementation, just don't need a separate method to check ownership. I've simplified it with async/await and the code is:

```
const addDocToDoc = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {
            user = ''
        } = req;
        const {
            id = '', doc2id = ''
        } = req.params;
        const doc = await Doc1.findById(id);
        if (!doc || !doc.user || doc.user !== user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Unauthorized User!!'
            });
        }
        doc.doc2s.push(doc2id);
        const updatedDoc1 = await doc.save();
        return res.status(200).json(updatedDoc1);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error While Updating Record!!',
            error: err
        });
    }
}
```

Ps: You may need some modification as i couldn't get a chance to run it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: While this handles searching the database for the document and only returning one if the user is the owner, this does not expose both error cases of 1) the document is not found - 404 (handled with your answer m) 2) the document is found but the user is unauthorized - 401

Comment: This also executes the exact same amount of calls to my database as by current solution with 2x the code. So this is not a DRY'er answer. My hope was that there was a middleware layer that I am able to pass and check the user-id before EACH update. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well we have **pre save()** middleware already available in mongoose, but if you specifically needs to throw unauthorized error, then that won't also work. In this case the way you are doing it is the best possible way. Though it needs some modification, I've added the simplified code in the answer

Comment: While I appreciate the response,  your additional code is handling the errors incorrectly as not finding a document is in requirement of a 404 server response. This does not fufil the given question and would recommend removing both responses as being a possible answer.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you trying to say, but if you need separate error to be thrown if no record, you can simply split the condition :)